# Is it bad idea to store my passwords on blockchain with a smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, security

I want to save my passwords and some other personal data on a ethereum like blockchain. it seems more persistant to me. I may lose my e-mail , my pc may crush and I may lose my usb stick. But nothing will happen to a blockchain.

I will encryp it and put `require(msg.sender,myaddress);`  to even read functions.
But still is there a way someone else can retrieve these information as it would be very  bad because they could just easily login to my wallets with that info and steal funds.

Comment: How could it be stored if nobody could read it but you? Everything on the ethereum blockchain is public because everyone has to be able to store it and verify it.

Comment: The great thing about Ethereum is that it works without having or requiring any trusted central parties. Your scheme requires some party that is trusted to hold non-public information and release it only to those authorized to have it. So it's not a good match to Ethereum's design. You would need to find some trusted party to do that for you and, at that point, how would the blockchain be helping you?